# Definition of Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring. Let $I\subseteq R$ such that

1. $I+I\subseteq I$
2. $IR\subseteq I$
3. $RI\subseteq I$.

Such an $I$ is called ideal of $R$.

**Can you check that is the definition true?**

Comment: How can a definition be true or not? It's just a definition. Or are you asking whether it coincides with classical definition? Then yes, it does. As in with the definition of "two-sided" ideal.

Comment: @freakish  Thanks. I did not understand second and third property that are these same?

Comment: They are not the same. Not in non-commutative rings.

Comment: @freakish Okey thanks.

Comment: I could, now how about you do?

Answer (score 0):

If you add $I\ne\emptyset$, it coincides with the usual definition of two-sided ideal as it is given for a non-commutative ring with unity $R$. However, in non-commutative ring theory, the notions of left ideal and right ideal get quite some usage.